# I need extension to create popup

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, plugin, extensions, modal

I'd like some advice. which extension is recommended for anyone needing to open an html page in a pop-up after clicking on an image?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [**Regular Labs Modals**](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modals#free-vs-pro). Go for the Pro Version, which offers more options.

> Modals is a Joomla plugin extension to help you create cool modal popup. You can make modal popups for texts, articles, other internal pages, external pages, images, videos, galleries...
>
> #### Full control
>
> **Modals is packed with options to control the modal popups.**
>
> - Full controll over styling (via some styling options and CSS)
> - Define dimensions and
> - Create image popups quickly and easily
> - Make galleries and slideshows automatically Pro only
> - Make popups open on pageload Pro only
> - And many more...
>
> #### Activators
>
> **There are several ways Modals can covert links:**
>
> - Via the special Modal tags {modal ...}...{/modal}
> - By class names (all links with defined class names)
> - All external links Pro only
> - By target="_blank" (all links with a target. Internal and/or external) Pro only
> - By filetypes (all links to given filetypes) Pro only
> - By url (also supports regular expressions) Pro only

Comment: thank you so much. This is a great plugin. create a pop-up to a web page becomes surprisingly simple. But in my case, it did not work. I tried several plugins and with anyone I managed to load the web page that I wanted. here is the link of the web page involved: http://www.nicovon.joomlafree.it/phocapanorama/output/sala_camino.html probably it can not load the page into the popup because it contains an ad.

Comment: then the contents of the pop-up fails to load: "This content failed to load."

Comment: @user63747 - i don't know what you are trying to do - the plugin is flexible and powerful and allows to create modals easily. There is documentation and a support forum at the developers website.

Comment: the problem is not about the plugin

Comment: @user63747:: In your question you ask about a plugin to help you create pop-ups - which has received 2 helpful responses that give you solution to your initial question. Then in your comment you say that the plugin didn't work to your case and I suggested you the extension's documentation and support forum - but now you say it's not about the plugin. I honestly can't help you. Your initial question has been answered. If you have problems with the plugin, ask the developer for support - if you have a new question or problems, then go ahead and open a new one, clarifying your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like Engage Box for anything popup/modal related.  I have suggested it on a few posts now, so I feel like a broken record.  However, I do use it on about 20 websites. There is a specific function for external websites.  It is easy to setup and has lots of extra features like setting cookies, custom page assignments, calling it through buttons, etc.

On the demo, try the "external website" option:
https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/engagebox

To set it up for clicking an image, you need to give the link an id and then setup the link to just be #.  So something like:

Then in the engage box settings, set the trigger point to "on Click" and then the trigger element would be #popupimage.  Important point... make sure the "Disable default action" is set to Yes.

Extension has good documentation: https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/engagebox/docs/the-onclick-trigger-point

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this free popup maker extension
https://www.everlive.net/joomla-extensions/18-create-popups-for-joomla.html

It is easy to use and simple.